# How can I give access to source code in TFS to for the purpose of a code review, without giving access to download the code?

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access, tfs-code-review

I am new to Microsoft Team Foundation Server, and I've had a request to give a 3rd party access to a project's source code for short amount of time for review.  The idea is to enable access for only a couple of days.

Is there a way to do this easily in TFS like what Fisheye provides?

To clarify, i realize that that by viewing code in a browser they are downloading code.  That is ok, I just want reduce their ability to download the whole project...  Does this make a difference?

Comment: It's close to trying to prevent people from reading the HTML source of a webpage. If you can view the code, you can download it in TFS.

Comment: Even if they only have a rendered bitmap image or printout of the code, someone on a mission to steal your code will succeed.  You may not be the one to make the decision - I understand - but I'd be really weary of doing business with someone who you think would want to steal your code.

Comment: The solution I am looking for isn't to make it impossible for someone that is totally determined to get a copy of the code.  I just don't want hand it over.  For example, you can browse files in a github repository as well as download it.  A workable solution would includ the browse aspect without the project/repo download.  Yes, they will have the source in as rendered in their browser, but wouldn't have a ready-made project to compile and deploy.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide them a locked-down and/or supervised physical workstation for the review.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's fundamentally no way to do this. Viewing the code is exactly the same as downloading the code.

I suppose TFS could create an image (.bmp, .jpg or .png) from the code and then display that to the reviewer, but that's a fairly rare request.

You could provide read access to the code but no access to the project and solution files, or other components necessary to successfully produce a product from the code.